# onbackpressed animation weird behaviour

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, translate-animation

I have implemented translate animation for my activity on back pressed.
The weird behavior is that, the previous activity comes in with the proper assigned animation. But the current activity doesn't show any animation. So it is like the previous activity is sliding in from the left side and on the right side, it is black. Could anyone please help me with this. 
Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    backpressed = 1;
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.right_out);

}
```

The animation code is:

Left in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Right out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" >

<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may move `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.right_out);` to `onCreate`

Comment: Tried this, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh. Looks godd!? I am doing exactly the same, but I have one minor differences. I don't have a `<set>` declared in both of my animations. what does it do?

Right Out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:duration="@integer/animation_transistion_length_short"
  android:fromXDelta="0%"
  android:fromYDelta="0%"
  android:toXDelta="100%"
  android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

Any differences?

Comment: Nope, no difference. Still the same. However, when i was running the program on a note 2 with 4.1.2 and it gave me this problem. But when i ran this in nexus s(4.1.2) and nexus 4(4.2.2), it was working fine. Don't know why is it behaving like that.